# Error with Slb.License when registering module

Tags: ocean, petrel

I have a project that references Slb.License for Ocean2010 licensing.  I am building against Petrel 2010.1.

After I install my plugin on a machine running >Petrel 2010.1 (2010.2.2), I use the registermodule.exe to register my modules.  All modules register correctly except the license module which has references to Slb.License.

RegisterModule.exe gives me an error :
"The specified module can not be loaded. Reason:Could not load file or assembly '
Slb.License, Version=2009.1.4.32700, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=05cb3974809
3345b' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition do
es not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

The version in the error, 2009.1.4.32700, is the version of Slb.License that is packaged with Petrel 2010.1 which I am building against.  The version of Slb.License that is packaged with Petrel 2010.2.2 is 2010.1.5.21635.

Any thoughts ?  If I manually add my license module to the Petrel.exe.config, my plugin loads correctly and works correctly.  Its RegisterModule.exe that I have the issues with.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
This was working in the previous build but not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can check: 
- RegisterModule uses petrel.exe.config to get binding redirects. You should see

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Slb.License" publicKeyToken="05cb39748093345b" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2009.1.4.32700-2010.1.4.63024" newVersion="2010.1.5.21635" />
```

there 
- Make sure there is only 1 copy of Slb.License.dll in Petrel area

As a workaround you can use /f option which ignores any error and register your module.

Comment: Yes I see the binding redirects in the Petrel.exe.configs. I can't use the /f options for registermodule.exe from an ocean installer.